# How to log an installation made from a WiX bundle

Tags: logging, wix

When creating a Windows installer using the WiX (Windows Installer for XML) toolset, how do you make the install process write logging information to a log file?

Is there a command-line switch which triggers the output of the log file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Bundle will automatically log to the %TEMP% location. A specific location for the log file can be set by passing a path to `-l` or `-log` such as: `bundle.exe -l "path\to\your\log.txt"`

More details are provided by [FireGiant](http://www.firegiant.com) at the bottom of [this article:](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-)

Comment: You can also add a <Log PathVariable="c:\TEMP\installerlog.txt"/> line under <Bundle>. I used this in a bootstrapper project, might work in others too but I have not checked that.

Comment: I see that `Engine.Log` method has a `LogLevel` parameter. In my experience, messages with `LogLevel.Debug` are not written to the log file. Is there a way to make the installer write the debug messages as well?

Comment: Found the answer: this is currently not supported by the Bootstrapper engine (except by setting a global logging policy). See http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-logging-td6698359.html .

Answer (score 4):

You need to run your installation from the command line (preferably from an administrative command prompt) and use the -l switch as follows:

mySetup.exe -l "LogFileName.log"