# SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, signtool

I created a Xamarin App (VS 2022). I would like to sideload the UWP so I am trying to create an App Package using the publish menu option in the UWP project.
The app compiles and is signed with a PFX key file under the regular build and the App Manifest uses a certificate that i created.

when i try to publish i get this error:

Failed to sign 'XXXXX.UWP_2.0.29.0_x86.msix'. SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1

```
For more information, please see https://aka.ms/badexeformat
```

SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: XXXXX.UWP_2.0.29.0_x86.msix

what am i setting up wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I was facing this issue when signing a Wix bundle. The reason was that the order of the signatures being applied was wrong (was signing the outer package before the inner package, to put it simply).

It's a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596548/how-to-log-an-installation-made-from-a-wix-bundle).